# networkx: remove nodes without also removing connected edges

Tags: python, networkx

I am using networkx shortest_path function to compute shortest travel distance. However, the size of my G file is close to 15 GB because I use the entire road network for the greater LA area, as individuals in my sample can travel from Riverside County to LA County. I am looking for ways to reduce the size of my G file, because I want to do multiprocessing. I know networkx has a lot of ways to simplify G, however, I am reluctant to do so because I need a high precision for travelling distance for my project, but please let me know if you know ways to simplify G without compromising on the precision for travelling distance.

Anyway, I'm thinking of removing all the nodes from G except the nodes that are origin-destination pairs from my sample, while keeping all the edges, as I need edge distance. I wonder if this is feasible for me to still use the shortest_path function. I tried the following codes:
`G.remove_nodes_from(list(G.nodes))`.
I thought it would remove all the nodes while keeping all the edges. However, it removed all the nodes and edges.

Any comments are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: what's is your code where you specify *"origin-destination pairs from my sample"*?

Comment: there are a sample of origin-destination pairs for which I would like to compute travel distance for. I find the nearest nodes for each origin and destination, and wish to only keep these nodes in my G.

Comment: Give a testable sample as a simple prototype of your graph: show input and output.

Comment: The question is, what do you mean by "keeping all the edges"? Do you mean you want to keep edges between nodes that no longer exist in the network?